# What is the proper way to enable the css prop in Emotion 11/Next js 10 apps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, emotion

The `css` prop is not recognized at build time. I'm unsure if this is due to misconfiguration of the project, or if this represents a known bug.

> Type '{ children: (string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal | Element)[]; className: string; css: SerializedStyles; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { theme?: Theme; as?: ElementType; } & ClassAttributes & HTMLAttributes<...> & { ...; }'. Property 'css' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { theme?: Theme; as?: ElementType; } & ClassAttributes & HTMLAttributes<...> & { ...; }'

To reproduce:

https://github.com/jbcurrie/jbcurrie.github.io/tree/next

1. npm install
2. open `NavMenu.tsx`
3. Inspect Line 18

Expected behavior:

The `css` prop should be recognized at build time.

Environment information:

- react version: 17.0.1
- next version: 10.0.5
- @emotion/react version: 11.1.5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If using the automatic runtime, you should be able to fix the issue by adding the following to your `tsconfig.json`.

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
    }
}
```

Alternatively, add the following to your `next-env.d.ts`, which adds support for the `css` prop globally for all components, when not using the automatic runtime.

```js
/// <reference types="@emotion/react/types/css-prop" />
```

Check [Emotion's TypeScript documentation](https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#css-prop) for more details.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up modifying the tsconfig, as mentioned in the docs, since this app is using the automatic runtime. 
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
  }
}
`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working config with emotion and Next.js

```
npm install @emotion/react @emotion/styled && npm i --save-dev @emotion/babel-plugin
```

```
yarn add @emotion/react @emotion/styled && yarn add -D @emotion/babel-plugin
```

```
.babelrc

{
  "presets": [
    [
      "next/babel",
      {
        "preset-react": {
          "runtime": "automatic",
          "importSource": "@emotion/react"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@emotion/babel-plugin"]
}
```

```
package.json

"dependencies": {
    "next": "10.1.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
},
"devDependencies": {
   "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.3.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wan't to leave some info here, since I can't comment on the accepted answer.

For some reason that I don't now yet, when I choose this option:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
    }
}
```

My typescript begin to be conflicted with vite-plugin-svgr types and an error appear, that component type cannot be "Element | Null".

To fix that I just used the second option:

```
/// <reference types="@emotion/react/types/css-prop" />
```

**Little fix: If I not mantain both of them, my app lose all styles, but if I mantain reference and the jsxImportSource, everything worked fine**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34944189)

Answer (score -4):

`// @ts-ignore`

Add this above the line where you use the css props, this will prevent the error - useful if you rarely use it, not so great if you have them all throughout your app.

Comment: This answer could use supporting information to identify why it fixes this issue, and provide information about any consequences from using it, rather than simply saying, as you have "not so great..." etc.